# jQuery: how to make dialogue box stay at top right corner even with scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://tympanus.net/Development/WebsiteTour/

The black dialogue box with next and previous button at the top right corner is what I want.

What jquery library allows this? Basically when you scroll, it stays at that top right corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not jquery. It is simple CSS.

Use `position:fixed;` and the box will stay in its position even if you scroll

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7RPfC/)

Comment: how do i make it stay on the right corner and change the color of the contents font?